How to accept argument using inheritance?
I understand that the parent class can be the type that hold the child class;
For example:
`Object o=new Student("stuname");` 

List<Object> l=new ArrayList<>();
l.add(3);
l.add("apple");

Both these two cases will work.
Then why it doesn't work when working as function parameter?
For example:
`void test(List<Object> l){
}

List<Student> stulist=....;
test(stulist);`

This will not work.

Here is the complete test code I generated for this problem.
And the compiler error occurs when running the codes starred.
I guess I have some misunderstanding about the generics or polymorphism here. Hope that anyone can point out to make me clearer about why this issue happens.

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println("Hello, World!");
      
      List<Object> l=new ArrayList<>();
      l.add(3);
      l.add("apple");
      List<Student> relation=new ArrayList<>();
      
      relation.add(new Student("Join",null));
    
      //Student.test(relation); //****will generate error here**
      Student.test2(relation); //****will also generate error here**
      
  }
  
  
  static class People {
    String name;
    
    public People(String name){
      this.name=name;
    }
  }
  
  static class Student extends People{
    String name;
    List<People> relations;
    
    public Student(String name,List<People> relations){
      super(name);
      this.relations=relations;
    }
    
    
    public static void test(List<People> l){
      System.out.println("ok");
    }
    public static void test2(List<Object> l){
      System.out.println("object ok");
    }
  }
}

Here is the error:
 Main.java:14: error: method test2 in class Student cannot be applied to given types;
 Student.test2(relation);
              ^
 required: List<Object>
 found:    List<Student>
 reason: argument mismatch; List<Student> cannot be converted to List<Object>
 1 error
 error: compilation failed


Why would you want to allow test to add "apple" to a List<Student>?
